# Pandas clean column and apply optional multiplier

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm using python and pandas. However this might be a regex question.... BE WARNED!

I have a dataframe similar to the following:

```
21    190000
27    170000
29    120k
31    110K
33    100000s
38    68ks
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
21    190000
27    170000
29    120000
31    110000
33    100000
38    68000
```

There might be some impurities in the data, such as trailing characters at the end not being numbers or in `[kK]` (as shown above).

I can find some of this by using `\d{3}k` however I'm unsure how to replace the 'k' part with the three '000' without affecting the first `\d{3}`. And how can I manage to get rid of the trailing characters? At the same time, before or after....

An approach would be fantastic a solution even more so.

I'm new to working with regexes so if you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need to use regular expressions for this, but if you want to:

```
# i am calling the specific column 'foo'
df = pd.DataFrame( [ '190000', '170000', '120k', '110K', '100000s', '68ks' ],
                   index=[21, 27, 29, 31, 33, 38], columns=['foo'] )

def clean( x ):
    from re import sub
    # \g<1> is whatever matches the the first (...)
    x = sub( r'(\d+)[kK]', r'\g<1>000', x )
    return sub( r'[^\d]', '' , x ) # remove any non-digit character

df.foo.map( clean ).astype( int )
```

if your numbers may have decimal digits, the return line should be changed to

```
    return sub( r'[^\d\.]', '' , x )
```

and you would need to cast to float:

```
df.foo.map( clean ).astype( float )
```

Comment: Just FYI this will fail if there are any NaN's in the string column. The pandas methods were built to work around missing observations. It seems to be somewhat faster though.

Comment: @TomAugspurger actually it unifies all forms of NaN such as 'na', 'N/A','NaN', etc to empty string "", which is easier to handle. you simply check for "" in the last line of `clean` function and return python representation of missing number which is 'nan'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string methods on pandas objects to strip the `s`'s and replace the `k`'s and `K`'s with `000`.

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
          1
0          
21   190000
27   170000
29     120k
31     110K
33  100000s
38     68ks

In [9]: df[1].str.rstrip('s').str.replace(r'[K|k]', '000').astype(int)
Out[9]: 
0
21    190000
27    170000
29    120000
31    110000
33    100000
38     68000
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

I recast the dtype to `int` at the end.